# Is it possible to change the number of values generated by an animation?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I created an animation (curve animation) in flutter and I reuse the values provided by this animation. According to my console, I can have 35 values.
Is it possible to have more values generated, like ~60?

Thanks

Comment: What animation did you create, and what kind of values you are talking about?

Comment: @CopsOnRoad I created this
`controller =
        AnimationController(duration: Duration(seconds: 1), vsync: this);
    animation = CurvedAnimation(parent: controller, curve: Curves.decelerate);`
And when try print(animation.value), I have 35 lines like 0, 0.671815380124, ...

Comment: Those values actually depend on how long the animation run, and what `curve` was used.

Comment: So I can't have more values in 1 secondes for this animation?  Because it's very fluid visully for my reuse.

Comment: Have you tried to use [Timer](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.1/dart-async/Timer-class.html) instead of `Animation`, you could get more value in 1 second as your wish.

Comment: @Tokenyet I want the animation lasts 1 second, no more. I wanted to change the frame rate, but it depends on the phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This value depends purely on the framerate and the animation length.

There's no "limited number of values" like your question is implying. A new value will be generated whenever needed, which is usually once per frame.

Comment: Can I change the frame rate?

Comment: No. It's defined by the device and the perfs of your app.